# postinstall > . n-nodeify --install --hack '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npx

postinstall > . n-nodeify --install --hack '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

While running this in the terminal of the visual studio of a react native project I am getting the above issue.

This is the script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating "postinstall" solved the issue, for windows we need this script

```
"postinstall": "npx rn-nodeify --install --hack"
```